# Error with Android Images when upgraded to Appcelerator 6.2.0 and Android 26

Tags: android, appcelerator

> ERROR] :  ViewSystem: ViewRootImpl #2 Surface is not valid. [ERROR] :
>   TiDrawableReference: (pool-4-thread-1) [95,95] Problem opening stream
>   with url /images/logo-half.png: Resources/images/logo-half.png [ERROR]
>   :  TiDrawableReference: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   Resources/images/logo-half.png [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:    at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method) [ERROR] : 
>   TiDrawableReference:  at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:364) [ERROR] :
>   TiDrawableReference:  at
>   android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:338) [ERROR] :
>   TiDrawableReference:  at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiFileHelper.openInputStream(TiFileHelper.java:222)
>   [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:   at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiDrawableReference.getInputStream(TiDrawableReference.java:863)
>   [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:   at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiDrawableReference.getBitmap(TiDrawableReference.java:319)
>   [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:   at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.view.TiDrawableReference.getBitmap(TiDrawableReference.java:303)
>   [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:   at
>   org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiLoadImageManager$LoadImageJob.run(TiLoadImageManager.java:128)
>   [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   [ERROR] :  TiDrawableReference:   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) [ERROR] : 
>   MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null

Comment: Can you show a snippet of how your folder structure looks like for that image error? Also, are you sure it's working on other SDK versions?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.  Since moving to 6.2.0+ Android ALL images do NOT work.

Error:
Problem opening stream with url /images/logo.png: Resources/images/logo.png

Code:
image: '/images/logo.png'

Location:
Android>images>res-[density folder] (hdpi, mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi)

Running on device and simulator
Galaxy S8, Genymotion Pixel +